# How to connect device with no web browser to RADIUS WPA2 Enterprise wifi network

Tags: wifi, radius

I am trying to connect a Bresser 5-in-1 Weather Station to a workplace's wifi network, which uses RADIUS WPA2 Enterprise security. From a laptop or smartphone I can connect to the network and then enter my credentials (user name and password) to get on the Internet, but this won't work with the Weather Station since it lacks a web browser. The only configuration that I can perform on it is through a dedicated web-based screen that I access from a local computer.

Is there a way to connect a device like this, with no browser, to a RADIUS WPA2 Enterprise network? Thanks.

Comment: MAC Authentication Bypass?